# Custom parameters in URL for show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, seo

I'm working on implementing a SEO-hiarchy, which means that I need to prepend parameters for a show action.

The use-case is a search site where the URL-structure is:
`/cars/(:brand)/` => a list page
`/cars/(:brand)/(:model_name)?s=query_params` => a search action
`/cars/:brand/:model_name/:variant/:id` => a car show action

**My problem is to make the show action URLs work without having to provide** `:brand`, `:model_name` **and** `:variant` **as individual arguments**. They are always available from as values on the resource.

What I have:
`/cars/19330-Audi-A4-3.0-TDI`

What I want
`/cars/Audi/A4/3.0-TDI/19330`

Previously, this was how the `routes.rb` looked like:

```
# Before
resources :cars. only: [:show] do
  member do
  get 'favourize'
  get 'unfavourize'
end
```

Following was my first attempt:

```
# First attempt
scope '/cars/:brand/:model_name/:variant' do
  match ":id" => 'cars_controller#show'
  match ":car_id/favourize" => 'cars_controller#favourize', as: :favourize_car
  match ":car_id/unfavourize" => 'cars_controller#unfavourize', as: :unfavourize_car
end
```

This makes it possible to do:
`cars_path(car, brand: car.brand, model_name: car.model_name, variant: car.variant)`
But that is obviously not really ideal.

How is it possible to setup the routes (and perhaps the `.to_param` method?) in a way that doesn't make it a tedious task to change all `link_to` calls?

Thanks in advance!

**-- UPDATE --**

With @tharrisson's suggestion, this is what I tried:

```
# routes.rb
match '/:brand/:model_name/:variant/:id' => 'cars#show', as: :car

# car.rb
def to_param
  # Replace all non-alphanumeric chars with - , then merge adjacent dashes into one
  "#{brand}/#{model_name}/#{variant.downcase.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,'-').gsub(/-{2,}/,'-')}/#{id}"
end
```

The route works fine, e.g. `/cars/Audi/A4/3.0-TDI/19930` displays the correct page. Generating the link with `to_param`, however, doesn't work. Example:

```
link_to "car link", car_path(@car)
#=> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"cars", :action=>"show", :locale=>"da", :brand=>#<Car id: 487143, (...)>})
link_to "car link 2", car_path(@car, brand: "Audi")
#=> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"cars", :action=>"show", :locale=>"da", :brand=>"Audi", :model_name=>#<Car id: 487143, (...)>})
```

Rails doesn't seem to know how to translate the to_param into a valid link.

Comment: This is a really good and well-written question.  I think I have an idea and want to make sure I am on the right path (no pun intended).  Is it the case that you want to be able to use `cars_path(@car)` in your link_to's and have it generate the nice hierarchical URL from your views, but also have the router recognize "partial" URLs (e.g. `/cars/Audi`) as a request to list Audis?  Or is it an additional requirement for the link_to to be contextually aware (e.g. so it creates links to the /cars/:brand variant from some controller actions, but the full car URL from other controller actions?

Comment: Thanks, @tharrison. I think you got it right; I want to be able to use `cars_path(@car)` in my `link_to`. What action is being triggered can be controlled by constraints in the `routes.rb`. This means that urls for `cars/Audi` does not use `cars_path` but something like `brand_path(brand: "Audi")`.

Comment: OK, getting there, but I don't quite have it then :-). If you want to use named routes like brand_path, the argument would be an instance of the brand model ... although that could be like `brand_path(@car.brand)`.  Do you have a brand model and resources in the routes for that?

Comment: No, there is no model for "brand", "model_name" and "variant". It may seem counterintuitive, but it makes a lot of sense :) Besides the Car object, it's just strings.

Comment: Got it -- no, that makes sense (at least for model_name and variants, you might want to think about Brand just to ensure consistency of naming, etc.), just wanted to be sure :-)  OK, now I'll see if I can figure it out :-)

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: you create route just for cars_path helper, see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

I do not see any way to do this with Rails without tweaking either the URL recognition or the URL generation.

With your first attempt, you got the URL recognition working but not the generation. The solution I can see to make the generation working would be to override the `car_path` helper method.

Another solution could be, like you did in the UPDATE, to override the `to_param` method of Car. Notice that your problem is not in the `to_param` method but in the route definition : you need to give `:brand`,`:model_name` and `:variant` parameters when you want to generate the route. To deal with that, you may want to use a [Wildcard segment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) in your route.

Finally you can also use the [routing-filter gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter) which make you able to add logic before and after the url recognition / generation.

For me, it looks like all theses solutions are a bit heavy and not as easy as it should be but I believe this came from your need as you want to add some levels in the URL without strictly following the rails behavior which will give you URL like `/brands/audi/models/A3/variants/19930`

Answer (score 1):

OK, so here's what I've got.  This works in my little test case.  Obviously some fixups needed, and I am sure could be more concise and elegant, but my motto is: "make it work, make it pretty, make it fast" :-)

In `routes.rb`

```
  controller :cars do
    match 'cars', :to => "cars#index"
    match 'cars/:brand', :to => "cars#list_brand", :as => :brand
    match 'cars/:brand/:model', :to => "cars#list_model_name", :as => :model_name
    match 'cars/:brand/:model/:variant', :to => "cars#list_variant", :as => :variant
  end
```

In the Car model

```
  def to_param
    "#{brand}/#{model_name}/#{variant}"
  end
```

And obviously fragile and non-DRY, in `cars_controller.rb`

```
  def index
    @cars = Car.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @cars }
    end
  end

  def list_brand
    @cars = Car.where("brand = ?", params[:brand])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
    end
  end

  def list_model_name
    @cars = Car.where("brand = ? and model_name = ?", params[:brand], params[:model])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
    end
  end

  def list_variant
    @cars = Car.where("brand = ? and model_name = ? and variant = ?", params[:brand], params[:model], params[:variant])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm sorry @tharrison, but I think you got it wrong. The issue is not displaying brand, model_name or variant pages. That stuff already works. The problem is linking directly to _one single_ car record. For this to work, I have to use the car ID, and additionally, I want to add brand, model_name and variant to the URL (for SEO purposes). So what I want is: link_to cars_path(@car) to point to /cars/:brand/:model_name/:variant/:id. Does that make sense?

Comment: Jonas, I think the code I provided is a millimeter away from what you want.  Add or modify the `match` clauses as needed by adding the `:id`.  The ':as => :foo` argument is what allows you to reference the URL as `foo_path`, and the `to_param` override is what produces the pretty path -- format it however you like and add id, or whatever other attributes of Car you like in order to get the nice URL.  Right?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The routing works perfect the way you suggested. The problem is that Rails cannot translate the implementation of the `to_param` into a link. I've updated my question with a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create two routes, one for recognition, one for generation.

**Updated**: use the routes in question.

```ruby
# config/routes.rb
# this one is used for path generation
resources :cars, :only => [:index, :show] do
  member do
    get 'favourize'
    get 'unfavourize'
  end
end
# this one is used for path recognition
scope '/cars/:brand/:model_name/:variant' do
  match ':id(/:action)' => 'cars#show', :via => :get
end
```

And customize `to_param`

```ruby
# app/models/car.rb
require 'cgi'

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    parts = [brand,
             model_name,
             variant.downcase.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,'-').gsub(/-{2,}/,'-'),
             id]

    parts.collect {|p| p.present? ? CGI.escape(p.to_s) : '-'}.join('/')
  end
end
```

Sample of path helpers:

```ruby
link_to 'Show', car_path(@car)
link_to 'Edit', edit_car_path(@car)
link_to 'Favourize', favourize_car_path(@car)
link_to 'Unfavourize', unfavourize_car_path(@car)
link_to 'Cars', cars_path
form_for(@car) # if resources :cars is not
               # restricted to :index and :show
```

Answer (score 0):

You want bounded parameters to be passed to url of which some parameters are optional and some of them strictly needs to be present.

Rails guides shows you can have strict as well as optional parameters and also you can give name to particular route in-order to simplify its usage.

Guide on rails routing
[bound parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters)

Example usage -

In below route,

- `brand` is `optional parameter` as its surrounded by `circular bracket`
- Also please note there can be optional parameters inside route but they needs to added at last `/cars(/:brand)(/:make)(/:model)`

  `match '/cars/(:brand)', :to => 'cars#index', :as => cars`

here `cars_url` will map to index action of cars controller..
again `cars_url("Totoya")` will route index action of cars controller along-with `params[:brand]` as `Toyota`

Show url route can be as below where id is mandatory and others can be optional

```
match '/cars/:id(/:brand(/:model_name/)(/:variant)', :to => "cars#show", :as => car
```

In above case, `id` is mandatory field. Other parameters are optional.
so you can access it like `car_url(car.id)` or `car_url(12, 'toyota')` or `car_url(12, 'toyota', 'fortuner')` or `car_url(12, 'toyota', 'fortuner', 'something else)`